# Excel. Use vba to record when someone removes the shared feature

Tags: vba, excel

We have a problem at work. Im not sure if this is due to an individual or the system admin applying patches during working hours but... we use an Excel sheet at work to track engineering work. It is a shared workbook so that multiple people can work at any time and is working well. Recently people have been losing their work because something is removing the shared status from the file during the day. It is only discovered when people go to save their work or open the workbook again after lunch. Is it possible to write a macro that records when the shared feature is applied or removed. I assume it is a property of the workbook collection/object but cant see how to do it from the docs

Comment: Consider modifying the menus to remove the **enable/disable sharing** option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `Workbook.MultiUserEditing` property.

This code snippet ([from Microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080554841.aspx)) would save the workbook in shared mode if the workbook is not currently in shared mode.

```
If Not ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        accessMode:=xlShared
End If
```

You may consider placing this code (or similar) in the `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event or other relevant event.

Comment: Thanks Josh That looks nice and simple.